# Need help to write xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath

As I am a beginner in selenium. I want to join both the class: class='criteria-label' and class="criteria-value" and write an XPath .Kindly can someone help me?

```
<li _ngcontent-bio-c430="" xpath="1"><div _ngcontent-bio-c430="" class="container__pad-bottom"><label _ngcontent-bio-c430="" style="display: block;"><span _ngcontent-bio-c430="" class="criteria-label">Last Name</span></label><p _ngcontent-bio-c430="" class="criteria-value"> = SITA </p></div></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your xpath should look like that:

```
//*[contains(@class, 'criteria-label') or contains(@class ,'criteria-value')]
```

To experiment, learn and validate xpath I can recommend [xpather](http://xpather.com/) and this [cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath).

### Edit

To join both texts you can use `string-join()`:

```
string-join((//span[@class='criteria-label']/text(),//p[@class ,'criteria-value']/text()),'')
```

Comment: thank you. we are getting 2 results for this

Comment: Is it any way to get a unique XPath. Now we are getting 2 results. My automation is failing.

Comment: That is a good point und should be used to improve your question - Edited my answer so that you get one string back. That was your goal right?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.